# При клике передать заголовок в инпут

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

Есть скрипт который передает при клике заголовок ссылки в инпут.

Сейчас ссылкой обернут только заголовок товара.

Если обернуть ссылкой весь блок включая изображение товара, то при клике передается в инпут весь код который находится внутри ссылки

**Вопрос - как мне изменить скрипт чтобы он передавал только заголовок (сам текст)?**

**Верстка товара**

```
<a name="menu-title" onclick="Zack(this);">
    <div>    
    <img src="foto.png" alt="alt">                  
    заголовок
    </div>
</a>
```

**Инпут , куда передается заголовок**

```
<input type="text" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value=this.title;" 
onfocus="if(this.value==this.title) this.value='';"  name="zakaz"  value="" >
```

**Сам скрипт**

```
    <script>
var First = true;
function Zack (MenuTitl) {
    var zakaz = document.getElementsByName('zakaz')[0];
    zakaz.value = MenuTitl.innerHTML.replace(/^\s*/,'').replace(/\s*$/,''); 
}
</script>
```

Comment: Добавьте `data-title` в ссылку и не парьтесь, считывая параметр. Парсить куски кода, такое себе

Answer (score 0):

```js
var First = true;
function Zack (MenuTitl) {
    var zakaz = document.getElementsByName('zakaz')[0];
    zakaz.value = MenuTitl.text.replace(/^\s*/,'').replace(/\s*$/,''); 
}
```

```html
<a name="menu-title" onclick="Zack(this);">
    <div>    
    <img src="foto.png" alt="alt">                  
    заголовок
    </div>
</a>

<input type="text" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value=this.title;" 
onfocus="if(this.value==this.title) this.value='';"  name="zakaz"  value="" >
```